# the arrival of a line of logs from filebeat towards elasticsearch

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

I have to verify the arrival of a line of logs from filebeat towards elasticsearch : Filebeat-> Redis > logstash-> elasticsearch

I know that I can do it with "Spring Data Elasticsearch".

Please, I need your help.

Thanks in Advance,